# Should I make that re-set password link expire at a certain period of time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, reset-password

## Form

[image]

When my user is `forgetting` their password, I asked them for an email so I can send them the re-set password link.

Right now I embeded the link into the btn, that link doesn't have any expiration time on it. But if they re-submit an email again, the I re-generate the link and override the old one.

---

## Questions

- Is what I'm having right now is secure enough ?
- Should I make that re-set password link expire at a certain period of time ?
- If so - What is the best practice to handle this ?

Any tips / suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: I personally store `reset_token` and `reset_token_expires_at` (which is usually set about 10 -15 minutes from "now". When the user clicks submit on the reset form, I check the expiration on the token and act accordingly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about security policy, not a specific programming problem. Asking on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: @castis : Do you mean I will need a table just a token ? What is the logic behind it ? How do I do that ? Do you mind give out a little more hints or answer it ?

Comment: @hopper : I completely disagree with you. This is also an application related which is laravel application which is php, and I asked laravel related question in here all the time. What so wrong about it ? I'm sure, new people that just started using laravel might have the same question as me.

Comment: @开发人员 Maybe I'm misreading the question, but it seems to be asking "Is what I'm doing secure enough?" and "Do I need to expire the link to be secure?". Those are (somewhat opinion-based) security questions rather than a programming ones. If the question is actually "How do I expire password reset links in Laravel?" that's a completely on-topic question, but the post should be edited to clarify the intent.

Comment: @开发人员 im storing the reset_token and the expiration in the users table. when they put in their new password and click submit, i `update users set password = '$hashed', reset_token = '', reset_token_expires_at = '' where reset_token = '$submitted_token' and reset_token_expires_at < now()`

Comment: interesting discussion on this topic: [Are password reset links that don't expire a security risk?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24260/are-password-reset-links-that-dont-expire-a-security-risk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using laravel 5, this option comes as a boiler plate. all you have to do is migrate the users and password_reset tables. The token is automaticaly expired in 60 minutes.

Comment: @开发人员 just use the /auth/password route on your laravel app